# Network cable is plugged in, but iMac isn't recognizing connection

Tags: ethernet, imac

So, while doing a little home networking, I decided to place my iMac on a ethernet connection. Well I plugged in the ethernet cable and normally it will recognize the present cable but not immediately recognize an internet connection (normal), but it is saying that the cable is not even in. Does anyone know what would cause this? I have taken the same cable and plugged it into my MacBook and my MacBook recognizes the cable and registers on the DHCP server.

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated! Thanks!

**MORE MYSTERY:** 
 When I plug an ethernet cable into my MacBook and plug the other end into my iMac, my iMac will recognize the cable [O.o]... *the weirdness continues...*

Comment: Reboot your iMac, see if the behavior reoccurs.

Comment: @Paul I actually unplugged it and let it sit for a few hours. No change.

Comment: Couple questions: Have you had your home network configured and working before using this iMac? What has changed since then if yes?

Comment: Well there is a central switch/router in my place and it distributes internet among my apartment, I did switch around a few cables, but the ethernet port I am attempting to hook my iMac up to IS functional and working.

Comment: Well, at this point I guess because you have confirmed your laptop works on that cable and port, we have to assume it's the iMac and so I'd begin by checking the network preferences. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1317 scroll down to "Check Network preferences settings".